# How we can determine "IsPartial" inside razor view in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can we determine in which mode the view has been rendered, inside of the view (`.cshtml` file)?

Actually, in a view, for example `Delete.cshtml`, I have called the `Details.cshtml` as :

```
@Html.Partial("Details.cshtml",model)
```

and inside of the `Details.cshtml` view, I want to determine the rendering type (Full/Partial) to make a decision for some jobs.

Is there any `IsPartial` property or something like that?

Comment: I don't think there is a mechanism for the view to know that is what you did, but why not add a property onto the viewmodel to that effect

Comment: simple use two view: one for full view, and second for partial

Comment: It's not really the norm to render a view as both a full view i.e. `return View("MyView");` or as `@Html.Partial("MyView")`. Your better off making a partial view with the full knowledge that it will never be used as a full view. Your just making things harder for yourself.

Comment: @Grundy it does not seems good idea, because 99% of Full views and Partial ones are the same , and there is just a little difference between theme. and in other hand , i have many many full views which should i create a clone and partial one for theme!

Comment: @AliAdl not good if your partial is same as full :-), anyway you can use property in model as suggest _3dd_

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible directly from **Html.Partial** but  it is possible if you go to that view using an action and render it using **Html.Action**.

say you want to pass foo as model, make it first

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an action

```
public ActionResult Details(Foo _foo)
{
    return PartialView(_foo);
}
```

call it like

```
@Html.RenderAction("FooBar", "Controller", new { Name = "John", Age=20 });
```

Now by doing so, You can determine weather this action is called from another action or not

```
 if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
            return PartialView(_foo);
```